# Loading 6 millions triangles crashes browser with Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, geometry

I have an array of 18441816 vertices ( ~6 millions of triangles) and the same array length with colors attribute. I load this mesh using ThreeJS buffergeometry.

Most of the time, my browser crashes when calling BufferAttribute.Call during geometry.addAttribute('position',...).

And sometimes, it succeeds to load my model.

What is the best practice to load such a model?

Comment: Well, you can't load infinitely complex geometry data into an app. Consider to lower the amount of triangles in order to mitigate such issues.

Comment: I will look if I can decrease my triangles. But I do not understand why sometimes it loads?

Comment: Can you break it apart until say 6 meshes of 1 million triangles each? 60 meshes of 100k triangles each? It might help. Browsers limit the amount of memory JavaScript has access to. Big chunks of memory require a continuous piece of memory but memory might be fragmented so sometimes there's a piece big enough and it works, other times there is no piece big enough and it fails. By using smaller pieces that becomes less likely to happen.